# Is there any way to access the control templates used by office 2007

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, office-2007, controltemplate

In WPF, the default scrollbars are boring light blue controls, however I noticed that Office 2007 has some really nice scrollbars with animated color transitions.

Does Microsoft provide these visually pleasing scrollbars in WPF? (Via a template or any other method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The closest provided by Microsoft would be the [themes in the WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes&referringTitle=Home).  There are quite a few [3rd party options](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/WpfThemes/default.aspx) to get the Office 2007 styles in WPF applications, however.

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I was hoping for, but I do appreciate the link to the WPF Toolkit.

Comment: For others that come along, there is also the office UI at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx . I didn't bother to sign up, but if you want the ribbon, thats the place to go.